# Stockholm - Newark, connecting for a domestic flight

Tags: transit, ewr

I have booked a trip from Stockholm to Newark airport. I have bought separate tickets for my domestic flight to Alabama. I will arrive in Newark 1 pm and my domestic flight is at 7 pm. That gives me about 6 hours to pick up my luggage, change terminal, check in and board again. Will I make it?
What terminal would I arrive in (international) and what terminal would I fly from (domestic)

Comment: 6 hours are plenty of time, even for the most complicated connection. The only trouble is if your flight arrives late.

Comment: Yes, you will, with plenty of time. No way to know terminals without knowing airlines so just check on the [live info board](https://www.panynj.gov/airports/flight-status.html?view=&apt=EWR) for yours.

Answer (score 1):

Two hours is typically plenty.

But if your flight is significantly delayed, like for 8 hours, nothing helps. This is a small chance, but not predicable.
Personally, I have often done such combinations, and I feel comfortable with a 4 hours; never failed yet.